# REST API call to Azure Data lake Storage Gen 2 not working. Giving me error "Audience validation failed. Audience did not match"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm using the REST API to list all the queues in my azure data lake storage account.

But I am getting this error:

> "Audience validation failed. Audience did not match"

Comment: Hi Souvik Dutta Choudhury, I am just curious if my answer solved your issue. If it did, please make it as answer, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Per my understanding, you are using [Azure AD for the authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authenticate-with-azure-active-directory). Please find the steps as below.

1.[Register an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-add-azure-ad-app)

2.[Assign a build-in RBAC role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json) to this application. It depends on you which role to be assigned to the application.

3.get access token. Please note to use https://storage.azure.com/ as resource

[image]

4. call the rest api.

[image]